# PyQt5. How to center buttons within QHBoxLayout?

Tags: python, pyqt5

I want the buttons to remain as small as possible, and bunch up into the center of the HBox instead of gravitating right.

```
import sys
from random import randint
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QFrame, QHBoxLayout, QPushButton, QVBoxLayout, QWidget, QLabel

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
Frame = QFrame()

vbox = QVBoxLayout(Frame)
for i1 in range(5):
    hbox = QHBoxLayout()
    hbox.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
    hbox.addStretch()

    for i2 in range(randint(1,10)):
        bb = QPushButton(str(i2))
        hbox.addWidget(bb)
    vbox.addLayout(hbox)

Frame.show()
app.exec_()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use the `setAlignment()` method on your layout to adjust the buttons centered in the parent QFrame:

```
hbox.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
vbox.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
```

If you want to use the `.addStretch()` function to fill the space before you may also use it again (after the inner for loop) to stretch the space after the buttons as well. A single stretch on the left side will expand and push the buttons to the right:

```
hbox.addStretch()  # epands and pushes to the right
for i2 in range(randint(1,10)):
    bb = QPushButton(str(i2))
    hbox.addWidget(bb)
hbox.addStretch()  # expands as well and compensates the first
```